# Is "shadows name from outer scopes an error"?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Hello I am writing a Python code and I am receiving the two variables underlined in green with "Shadows name 'value' from outer scope" and "Shadows name 'value1' from outer scope". Is this an error? And how can I solve this problem? My code should read two variables data from firebase realtime database. If both variables data are 1 then I should receive a notification on my phone. Is the code wrong?
Note that it was working normally and I was able to receive notification but when I added the second variable and modified the code I cant receive notifications anymore.

```
value = 0
value1 = 0


def stream_handler(message):
    print(message)
    if message['data'] is 1:
        value = 1 //here the variable is underlined in green
        value = value //here the variable is underlined in green
        return value


def stream_handler1(message1):
    print(message1)
    if message1['data'] is 1:
        value1 = 1 //here the variable is underlined in green
        value1 = value1 //here the variable is underlined in green
        return value1


if value is 1 & value1 is 1:

            response = pn_client.publish(
             interests=['hello'],
             publish_body={
                 'apns': {
                     'aps': {
                         'alert': 'Hello!',
                     },
                 },
                 'fcm': {
                    'notification': {
                      'title': 'Notification',
                      'body': 'Fall Detected !!',
                     },
                  },
             },
            )

            print(response['publishId'])


my_stream = db.child("Fall_Detection_Status").stream(stream_handler)
my_stream1 = db.child("Fall_Detection_Status1").stream(stream_handler1)
```

Comment: Hello Moustapha, just a question: are you using the Firebase Admin editor?

Comment: Please add information about the framework you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant this:

```
def stream_handler(message):
    global value
    print(message)
    # rest of function elided


def stream_handler1(message1):
    global value1
    print(message1)
    # rest of function elided
```

The `global` statements tell Python that you mean to use the global versions of the value variables and not have local versions.

Additionally you probably don't want statements like:

```
value = value
```

as this doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked and eliminated the green underlines.. but still my problem I cant receive the notification message when value is 1 and value1 is 1... any idea?

Comment: @MoustaphaSabbagh you may have more luck posting this other problem in a new question!